# Can a multiclassed Gunslinger/Slayer take the Grit rogue talent? If so, how does that work with Amateur Gunslinger?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rogue, gunslinger

One of the options for [slayer talents](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/slayer#TOC-Slayer-Talents) is picking a talent from a subset of the [rogue talent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents) list:

> Rogue Talent: A slayer can select one of the following rogue talents in place of a slayer talent: bleeding attack*, camouflage, combat trick, fast stealth, finesse rogue, firearm training, grit, hard to fool, lasting poison, powerful sneak, rogue crawl, slow reactions*, snap shot, sniper's eye, surprise attack, swift poison, terrain mastery, trap spotter, unwitting ally, or weapon training. Any talent effects based on rogue level use the slayer's class level. If the rogue talent has a prerequisite , the slayer must fulfill the prerequisite before taking that rogue talent. This talent can be selected multiple times; each time, it grants the slayer a new rogue talent.

One of the options in this list is ***Grit***. It's full description is:

> **Prerequisite:** Firearm training talent
>
> **Benefit:** A rogue with this talent gains the Amateur Gunslinger feat and one grit feat of her choice. She must fulfill the prerequisites of the grit feat in order to choose it.

The ***Amateur Gunslinger*** feat says the following:

> **Prerequisite:** You have no levels in a class that has the grit class feature.
>
> **Special:** If you gain levels in a class that grants the grit class feature, you can immediately trade this feat for the Extra Grit feat.

Does the prerequisite of the ***Amateur Gunslinger*** preclude a multiclassed Gunslinger/Slayer from taking the ***Grit*** rogue talent in order to gain an additional arbitrary grit feat? If not, how does this selection interact with ***Amateur Gunslinger***? Does the character in question simply not gain ***Amateur Gunslinger***, or does he/she immediately swap it for ***Extra Grit*** since he/she already has levels in a class that grants the grit class feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a character that first takes one or more levels in the class [gunslinger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/gunslinger) (or another class that gains the character the class feature [grit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/gunslinger#TOC-Grit-Ex-)) is prohibited from *taking* the feat [Amateur Gunslinger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/amateur-gunslinger-combat), such a character is *not* prohibited from taking the [rogue talent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents) [grit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/grit-ex). The character won't meet the prerequisite for the feat Amateur Gunslinger that comes from the rogue talent grit, but the character still gets the additional [grit feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/grit-feats) from the rogue talent.

Note that such a character would still *have* the feat Amateur Gunslinger, but the character won't realize any of that feat's benefits, and because the feat's source allows no *other* choices beyond that feat, the feat Amateur Gunslinger isn't eligible for [retraining](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining).

If, still later, such character gained *another* level in a class that granted the class feature grit (like an additional level of gunslinger), the character could immediately trade the feat Amateur Gunslinger for the feat [Extra Grit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-grit-grit). (This is strictly according to the rules as written. A kind GM may allow a character who already has the class feature grit who takes the rogue talent grit to immediately swap out the feat Amateur Gunslinger for the feat Extra Grit *without* mandating the character to take another level of, for example, gunslinger.)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on in which order you do gain your levels. If you get two levels of Slayer first, and then get a level in Gunslinger, the Amateur Gunslinger will get traded for Extra Grit. (Of course you would need to have Fire Arms training to choose the Rogue Grit too)

If you first get some levels of Gunslinger, yes you can choose the Grit talent as a Slayer, but you will not get the Amateur Gunslinger as you do not fulfill the prerequisite. You still would get the grit feat, though.

This is an example of how the order of choosing classes for multiclassing do matter.